# maven-jetty-plugin does not run application on contextPath

Tags: maven, web-applications, jetty

maven-jetty-plugin is always running application on default context path ('/'). I tried running by setting contextpath property to 'test' but it does not work. `http://localhost:8080/test` is not accessible. It still runs on default context path.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>9.1.0.M0</version>
    <configuration>
        <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
        <webApp>
            <contextPath>/test</contextPath>
        </webApp>
        <connectors>
            <!-- work around file locking on windows -->
            <connector implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector">
                <port>8080</port><!-- this connector defaults to 1300 for some reason -->
            </connector>
        </connectors>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

using only

```
<contextPath>/test</contextPath>
```

instead of

```
<webApp>
     <contextPath>/test</contextPath>
</webApp>
```

worked for me